# How do we know if we're in a vertex or a fragment shader?

Tags: include, glsl

We have some GLSL code in a shared file included both in vertex and fragment shaders (quite many of them). I'd like to ifdef a certain function based on whether it's included in a vertex or a fragment shader.

Is there a reserved word or a define that we can use for that?

Comment: I'm curious as to what kind of functions these would entail. I mean, you're talking about a function which is 1) appropriate for both a VS and an FS, and 2) will behave differently based on whether it is a VS or FS. A simple math function doesn't need VS or FS-specific features. And a function which needs, for example, `gl_FragCoord`, doesn't sound like a function that would be meaningful in a VS.

Comment: Functions grouped by scope, e.g. light projection. Sometimes I like to debug shaders with gl_FragCoord as one of inputs/filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you'll have to inject a define yourself.